# Meteor callback on some template render

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my meteor project, I have a code like this:

```
baz = function() {
    // some jQuery add/remove class here...
};

Template.foo.onRendered(function() {
    baz();
});

Template.bar.onRendered(function() {
    baz();
});

Template.qux.onRendered(function() {
    // no baz() call
});
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this task without repeat `baz();` on some template render?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor 1.2.1 allows you to run a global onRendered() function via the following code:

```
Template.onRendered(function() {
    var that = this; //pass that into baz() if you need it
    Deps.afterFlush(function() {
        console.log('baz');
        baz();
    });
});
```

If that doesn't fit your needs, and you want it on every page, just use onRendered() within some common template like the menu or page header, however this will not guarantee that the HTML you are attempting to alter with JQuery will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Brett answer, you could also use the `Template.body.onRendered(function(){..`

Each onRendered function is executed only once per template (when it loads).
The body (implicit) template, being the main container(parent) for the other templates(childs) will be executed on each page request.

Comment: Also a great answer!